# Why is Thanos called The "Mad" Titan?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron, thanos

Why is Thanos called "mad"? He is a master in strategy, adept in sciences far beyond Earth technology. In *Age of Ultron*, Thor happens to mention that someone is making things happen involving infinity gems and it is understood that Thanos is the brains behind this.

Of course he has this hunger for power and worships chaos. But many others had similar or madder thoughts.

But why is only Thanos given the title "Mad"? Is there any story explaining this?

Comment: "Mad" does not equal "stupid".

Comment: So what does "mad" mean and why?

Comment: Has anyone actually called him this in the MCU? I don't recall it happening.

Comment: http://marvel.com/characters/58/thanos Even the official marvel site does call him "The Mad Titan Thanos"

Comment: Yes, I know he is called that in the comics, but you reference the MCU and tagged the question as such. The backstory of the comics is not necessarily the same, and to my recollection, he has not *been* called "The Mad Titan" in the MCU, making it impossible to answer *why* he's called that in that universe.

Comment: [“You’re maaaad, Thanos!”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2x8RhadlpA)

Comment: “Of course he has this hunger for power and worships chaos.” He doesn’t worship chaos ([censorship notwithstanding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Surfer_(TV_series))). He’s in love with Death. Tewtally different thing bro.

Comment: Thanos literally wanted to kill half the universe in an attempt to impress a girl. If that isn't "mad", I don't know what is.

Comment: actually, he has been called that .... Corpsman Dey: Gamora. Surgically modified and trained as a living weapon. The adopted daughter of the Mad Titan, Thanos.

Comment: @phantom42 women can drive a man to do a lot of crazy things.

Comment: @Gautham "*Mad*" means "*Insane*", as in "*Crazy, but not in a good way*".  Also as in, "*Thanos, wants to do things that are so bad, they cannot possibly be of any benefit to him and will likely bring great harm to himself, let alone everyone else.*"  That kind of crazy.

Comment: Just for those not familiar with Corpsman Dey and Gamora, it's a line from Guardians of the Galaxy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Marvel](http://marvel.com/characters/58/thanos):

> The Mad Titan Thanos, a melancholy, brooding individual, **consumed with
>   the concept of death**, sought out personal power and increased
>   strength, endowing himself with cybernetic implants until he became
>   more powerful than any of his brethren.

[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mad):

> Full Definition of MAD
>
> 1: disordered in mind :  insane
>
> 2a: completely unrestrained by reason and judgment
>
> 2b: incapable of being explained or accounted for
>
> 3: carried away by intense anger :  furious
>
> 4: **carried away by enthusiasm or desire**
>
> 5: affected with rabies : rabid
>
> 6: marked by wild gaiety and merriment :  hilarious
>
> 7: intensely excited :  frantic
>
> 8: **marked by intense and often chaotic activity** :  wild

[Comicbook.com](http://comicbook.com/blog/2014/07/25/mad-titans-world-10-most-memorable-thanos-moments/):

> In an effort to court his longtime unrequited love Death, **Thanos
>   offers to kill half the Earth’s population in one fell swoop.** So he
>   snaps his fingers and *poof* billions of people disappear, just like
>   that.

He must be the only known live Titan to be so mad, as the rest seem to have [calmed down](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_%28Marvel_Comics%29):

> Under A'lars' leadership, **Titan became a haven for peace.** Then, A'lars
>   (also known as Mentor) sired the last two of his numerous children:
>   Eros and Thanos. Thanos was born a mutant, and grew up with dark
>   visions of conquest and destruction. Thanos left Titan, recruited an
>   army of mercenaries, and returned to attack. Only 100 of Titan's
>   thousands of inhabitants survived, and Sui-San perished in the
>   slaughter. Eventually, the Titanians rebuilt the colony and restored
>   it to a place of meditation and the pursuit of knowledge.

Comment: I think 2 a and b fit better

Comment: @cde - depends. #5 might fit if Rocket bites him.

Comment: @cde Why risk death or prison when you can rule beside Death while having your minions die for you?

Comment: @CeesTimmerman ?

Comment: @cde Why 2a and 2b don't fit.

Answer (score 5):

## He proposed genocide as a means of saving his planet from decay

In *The Avengers: Infinity War*, Thanos mentions to Tony Stark that his home planet, Titan, was being destroyed as it was hugely overpopulated. He tells Tony that his proposed solution was, in Tony's words "genocide", and that his people called him "mad" for it.

Comment: He was speaking to Dr. Strange, not Tony

Answer (score 1):

> But why is only Thanos given the title "Mad"?

That depends on the scope.

If you are only talking about the MCU then there a limited number of characters so giving too many of them the "title" "Mad" would be silly.

If you are talking about all Marvel characters then your assumption is wrong. There is at least one other called "Mad", the "[Mad Thinker](http://marvel.com/universe/Mad_Thinker)"

If you are talking about just the inhabitants of "Titan" then it's because of that group (and arguably of the entire universe) he was clearly the most angry, aggressive, violent, insane and dangerous. All attributes associated with the descriptor "Mad".

> Is there any story explaining this?

[Thanos Rising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanos_Rising) is probably the most thorough story covering his origins and possible reasons for his serious attitude problem.